# How can I extract the text between <a></a>?

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

```
</td>
        <td class="playbuttonCell">
        <a class="playbutton preview-track" href="/music/example" data-analytics-redirect="false"  ><img class="transparent_png play_icon" width="13" height="13" alt="Play" src="http://cdn.last.fm/flatness/preview/play_indicator.png" style="" /></a>    </td>
                                                        <td class="subjectCell" title="example, played 3 times">
            <div>
                                        <a href="/music/example"   >here lies the text i need</a>
```

this isn't doing the job

```
print soup('a')

for link in soup('a'):
    print html
```

prints everything, what else can i try?

Comment: Let's see what you tried with beautifulsoup

Comment: from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


webpage = urlopen('http://www.last.fm/user/natefanaro/charts?rangetype=overall&subtype=artists').read()

then i don't know what else to do.

Comment: @muchacho: that doesn't qualify as **using** BeautifulSoup.

Comment: ok, to be honest i have no idea what i'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.urlopen('http://www.last.fm/user/Jehl/charts?rangetype=overall&subtype=artists').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup('a')
# prints [<a href="/" id="lastfmLogo">Last.fm</a>, <a class="nav-link" href="/music">Music</a>....
```

For getting the text of each one of them.

```
for link in soup('a'):
    print link.get_text()
```

Comment: the thing is, the page has hundreds of those strings.http://www.last.fm/user/Jehl/charts?rangetype=overall&subtype=artists how can i proceed?