# How to extract the text between some anchor tags?

Tags: python, anchor, beautifulsoup, scraper

I need to extract the name of the artists from an HTML page. Here's a snippet of the page:

```
 </td>
 <td class="playbuttonCell">
   <a class="playbutton preview-track" href="/music/example" data-analytics-redirect="false"  >
      <img class="transparent_png play_icon" width="13" height="13" alt="Play" src="http://cdn.last.fm/flatness/preview/play_indicator.png" style="" />
    </a>
  </td>
  <td class="subjectCell" title="example, played 3 times">
    <div>
      <a href="/music/example-artist"   >Example artist name</a>
```

I've tried this but isn't doing the job.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urllib.urlopen('http://www.last.fm/user/Jehl/charts?rangetype=overall&subtype=artists').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup('a')

for link in soup('a'):
    print html
```

Where am I screwing up?

Comment: You are printing `html` instead of `link` inside your loop.

Comment: oh,yeah, i printed html to post the code here and forgot to change. but still not the solution i need, it prints the whole anchor tags.

Comment: I've already answered your question here and it works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233548/how-can-i-extract-the-text-between-a-a

Comment: Perhaps `str(link)` or `link.prettify()` is what you want?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu No. He needs `link.text` or `link.get_text()` as I've already answered him in the link above

Comment: i know, i've tested several times dude... maybe something is missing?

Comment: You've tested several times what? The code you've posted is wrong, why do you expect it to work?

Comment: An example of what you're getting and what you'd like to get would be nice.

Comment: Events
Charts
Community
Originals
Login
Join

                        English
        
Help
Get updates from Last.fm, follow us on Twitter »

                                                Deutsch
            

                                                Español
            

                                                Français
            

                                                Italiano

Comment: /\ that was the output from @rantanplan response

Comment: `soup.findAll('a')[3].text` returns *Events* and `soup.findAll('a')[11].text` returns *Get updates from Last.fm, follow us on Twitter »*, so I fail to see a problem with RocketDonkey's answer.

Comment: My response is the same as RocketDonkey's below and it's absolutely correct. I just tested it on my shell and it does *exactly* what you asked. It prints the text between the anchor tags.

Comment: guys, please have patience with me, i started to learn yesterday...

Comment: the text i need from that page are names of bands

Comment: That isn't what you initially asked muchacho. You should be more descriptive in your questions, we can't read your mind.

Comment: here lies the text i need = the bands

Comment: Now that you've mentioned what you really want, could you please update the question and mention that?

Comment: ok. you mean change the title too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
for link in soup.select('td.subjectCell a'):
    print link.text
```

It [selects (just like CSS)](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) the `a` elements inside `td` elements that have the *subjectCell* class.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: s = # Your string here...

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

In [4]: for anchor in soup.find_all('a'):
   ...:     print anchor.text
   ...:
   ...:

here lies the text i need
```

Here, the `find_all` method returns a list that contains all matching anchor tags, after which we can print the `text` property to get the value between the tags.

Comment: Isn't the `find_all` method name a bit more Pythonic? Also it doesn't exactly return an iterator, but a list.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Yeah, still have old BeautifulSoup methods in my head. As for the iterator comment, I blame the fact I'm up past my bedtime :)

Comment: @muchacho Don't copy and paste the `In [1]:` or the `...:`. These are the line numbers from his *ipython* terminal. It is not valid python.

Comment: it's possible to open multiple urls from a .txt and scrape the webpages content at once?

Comment: @muchacho Yep, you could wrap it in a `for` loop that iterates through the URLs, perhaps storing the matches in a new list. I would suggest reading about `for` loops and `open` - that should get you started :)

Answer (score 1):

```
spans = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "overlay tran3s"})
    for span in spans:
        links = span.find_all('a')
        for link in links:
            print(link.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

`soup.findAll` and `link.attrs` can be used to read the `href` attributes easily.

**Working code:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print (link.attrs['href'])
```

**Output:**

```
/music/example
/music/example-artist
```

Answer (score -2):

Regular expressions are your friend here. As an alternative to RocketDonkey's answer, which uses BeautifulSoup properly; you can parse through soup('a') with a regular expression like

```
>([a-zA-Z]*|[0-9]|(\w\s*)*)</a>
```

you can utilize the [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) method to grab the text in between the anchor tags directly.

Comment: Parsing html with regex is like dancing with a knight's armor.